# How can I animate an eye changing color?

Tags: modeling, color

I have a creature modle in the works right now and when its pupil narrows i want to be able to change the color of all parts of the eye. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I would set up a color ramp node between your two colors, then add a value node going into it. Keyframe the value node at your two points in time starting at 0 then going to 1, then the output of your color ramp with change between the two colors.

Comment: you can animate the color of a shader.  Just mouse over the color of the shader and press "I".  Does that help?  If not, could you show us the shading nodes you have?